# SQL 2005 Express not using materialized view in explicit query

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan

I know that Express edition of SQL Server 2005 does not include materialized views (with schemabinding) automatically while estimating optimal execution plan. However when the view is queried directly - i still get underyling table displayed in actual execution plan. Why isn't my clustered index created on materialized view used in the query?

Code for view is:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[athObjectNames] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT     convert(nvarchar(440),oTextValue) as oTextValue, oObjectID, oTypeID, oVersion
FROM         dbo.athObjects
WHERE     (oTypeID < 100)
```

And an unique clustered index is created on oTextValue columns.

However when I execute a query such as:

```
select * from dbo.athObjectNames
where oTextValue = 'Alibabki'
```

...i see that underlying table (dbo.athObjects) is used in execution plan with condition (oTypeID < 100). There is no index on oTextValue column of athObjects table. Even when I change the condition to "< 'Alibabki'" still index has no use.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004944/how-can-i-speed-up-this-indexed-view

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found that "with (noexpand)" hint should be used to force optimizer to use materialized view. Maybe this will help others. :-)