# Inserting 5.3M record into temp table is taking a long time

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I am inserting 5308194 records into this `#Temp` table, and it is taking about 8 seconds and was thinking that it shouldn't take that much time

Is there a better way to do this, or maybe BULK Insert, creating the temp table before the insert?

```
SELECT g.CustomerId, g.LogDate
INTO #Temp
FROM vwGuidelineLog g --nolock
WHERE g.LogDate >= '2017-10-01' 
  AND g.LogDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2018-09-30')
```

DDL

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwGuidelineLog]
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT        
        GuidelineLogID, LogDate, FileName, CustomerID, GuidelineLinkId, CountryId
    FROM            
        dbo.GuidelineLog
    WHERE        
        (GuidelineLinkId IS NOT NULL)
```

Clustered index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IdX_vwGuidelineLog] 
ON [dbo].[vwGuidelineLog] ([GuidelineLogID] ASC)
```

Index for `LogDate`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_GuidelineLogDate] 
ON [dbo].[vwGuidelineLog] ([LogDate] ASC)
```

Comment: DDL for `vwGuidelineLog ` is going to be really important here (I assume it's a view, based on it's name)

Comment: Well, waht hardwrawre? RAM? YOu are right, it could go faster - on a server with all SSD or something like that. Otherrwise, sorry, that is not realyl that bad, you know.

Comment: I would expect performance to improve with `CustomerID` as an included column on the view index.

Comment: Also, you forgot to include the view's clustered index DDL.

Comment: Is there an `INDEX` on `GuidelineLinkId` on the table `GuidelineLog`?

Comment: @Larnu No I didnt add any Index on the table itself just the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i speed up this Indexed View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004944/how-can-i-speed-up-this-indexed-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having an index on `GuidelineLinkId` isn't going to help, as that means that the Data Engine needs to scan the entire table. Considering that you have 5,308,194 rows that fulfil the requirement `GuidelineLinkId` IS NOT NULL AND logDate >= '2017-10-01' and LogDate < dateadd(day, 1, '2018-09-30'` I would guess you have a lot more rows than 5.3M in there. (so that's a lot to check).

I would, personally, consider adding an index on that column (probably with an `INCLUDE` on the other columns). Maybe:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_GuidelineLinkId
    ON dbo.GuidelineLog (GuidelineLinkId ASC)
    INCLUDE (GuidelineLogID, LogDate,LogDate, FileName, CustomerID, CountryId);
```

Dan's advice of altering the view `IDX_GuidelineLogDate` is also probably a good idea:

```
ALTER INDEX [IDX_GuidelineLogDate]
    ON [dbo].[vwGuidelineLog] ([LogDate] ASC)
    INCLUDE (CustomerID);
```

Comment: would I remove the index on the view then?

Comment: @Jefferson `IDX_GuidelineLogDate` is one of the indexes on your view.

Comment: Didnt think that I can have GuidelineLogID on both the table and view. 
 So [IdX_vwGuidelineLog] ON [dbo].[vwGuidelineLog] and dbo.GuidelineLog.IDX_GuidelineLinkId.

Comment: OH, sorry, you mean the clustered index, I had missed, sorry. The problem is the one on the `VIEW` isn't helping, as the `VIEW` still needs to be filtered.